# Window Messaging to Legacy Application

Tags: windows-messages

I developed an application of controlling other window using WindowsMessage. It works successfully with my sample application, which is build by C#.
However, then I tried to configure my controlling application with the legacy window, which is developed by VB6.0. Here I got 2 issues,

1) The following method returns false and textfield was not updated.

```
 IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;
 IntPtr lParam = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(text);
 bool retVal = Convert.ToBoolean(SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, wParam, lParam));
```

Can anybody help me to figure it out ?

2) When I scanned the sub-controllers in legacy application (using the window messaging),I found some controllers that their class names are **ThunderRT6FormDC**, **ThunderRT6UserControlDC**. What are these controllers ?

Answer (score 2):

2) The **ThunderRT6FormDC** and **ThunderRT6UserControlDC** are Visual Basic specific class names: VB sprang from an original project called Thunder and so the name stuck with a lot of the bits and pieces of VB code. Many VB window classes have **Thunder** in the name, including the 2 you saw.

1) My expectation is that the handle you fetched is not pointing at the right window: are you using Spy++ or a similar tool to look at the VB6 window and determine the proper text window, or are you setting the focus to the text window before sending the WM_SETTEXT message?

Comment: I fixed the Q1), 
I execute my legacy application in windows 7 and it has automatically enabled the security chesk of the exe. When I unchecked the security check WM_SETTEXT works fine.